# Two UITableViewCell have the same indexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a problem like this:

- I have a table view. when i click on a cell (or row), the cell will add 2 more buttons and re-size.

  - This function it work fine!
- The problem is when i click first row,

  - it creates 2 buttons and re-size
  - and then scroll down, another cell also display 2 buttons.
  - and this is my code for function of displaying button and resizing cell
- I believe when scrolling down the table is reloaded and reset the indexPath, so 2 cells both display the buttons.
  Anyone has any suggestion!?

---

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    tvcCategory *cell = (tvcCategory*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"- %i ", indexPath.item);
    if (selectedIndex.item != indexPath.item) {

        [btnEdit removeFromSuperview];
        [btnTransact removeFromSuperview];

        objSession.catId = cell.lblId.text;
        btnEdit = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnEdit.frame = CGRectMake(91, 72, 73, 35);
        [btnEdit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnEdit setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnEdit setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnEdit setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [btnEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToEditingScreen)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        btnTransact = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnTransact.frame = CGRectMake(176, 72, 95, 35);
        [btnTransact setTitle:@"Transact" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnTransact setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnTransact setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnTransact setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [btnTransact addTarget:self action:@selector(moveToTransactionScreen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        [tableView reloadData];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btnEdit];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btnTransact];
        lastClickedCell = cell;
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath;

        NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:-1 inSection:0];
        NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else
    {
        [tableView reloadData];
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

I really appreciate

Comment: Looks like a cell reuse problem. Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Comment: `UITableView`s re-use old cells. You scroll a cell out on one side, the next cell that gets scrolled into view might reuse the cell. Thus, if the re-used cell had some buttons added to it, it will still have those buttons. Clean your cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are facing, like the guys has had exposed in the comments is that in the table view method you need to reuse cells to optimize the performance, so you need to take this cells that are already used and adjust it to your expected cell state.

Probably in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are just taking care to allocate it and adjust it when you do not have a cell, you will need to adjust it, you have some options, like always adjust it to the initial state or you can check if the buttons are showed and only in this cases redesign your cell.

So in your class, at some point you have this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    } else {
        if([selectedIndex isEqual:indexPath]){
           //Add your buttons and adjust the cell to show the extra buttons
        } else {
           if(your selected index isn't in the screen anymore){
               [btnEdit removeFromSuperview];
               [btnTransact removeFromSuperview];
           }
           //your others adjusts
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
[[yourTable indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:selectedIndexPath];
```

This method return an array that you need to check if your selectedindex is inside it.
More about UITableView you can found at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You are removing the buttons? I will do an edit in the answers.

Comment: so you mean, i have to do both adding and removing my button in both cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath !?

Comment: yep, because your selected index can go out of the screen and then come back again, and you have less cells than index in your table, sou you need to manage that whenever when a cell comes to the screen, if it has been used by the selected index you need to remove, if it is the selected index you will need to add it.

Comment: how can i detect if my selectedIndex isn't in the screen anymore. Because my selectedIndex is global. I tried these code to detect if my selectedIndex is in screen or not. for (NSIndexPath *temp in [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]) {
                if (![selectedIndex isEqual:temp]) {
                    [btnEdit removeFromSuperview];
                    [btnTransact removeFromSuperview];
                }
           }